# OSX Application Crashing in release mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2, xcodebuild, release-mode

Any pointers how can we debug an application in the release mode, its crashing even a first line it self , below is the code snippet

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    debugLog<<" inside app did finish launching "<<endl;

    **// here its crashing**        
    [self InitAppController];

    [AppUtil createAppMacFolder];


}
```

Comment: What are the particulars of the crash? Is it an exception? What is logged to the console? Show the (poorly-named) `-InitAppController` method's code.

Comment: To protect confidentiality i had to change the few methods name, but below answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what was the problem,
But when i set the optimization level to 0 was working fine,

[image]

Comment: This is almost surely just hiding the problem, at best. It will probably crop up under random circumstances if you leave it at that. If you have a crashing bug, you are **lucky** that it was reproducible during development. Also, it should be readily fixable if you provide more details.